# C# checking if order number already exists

Tags: c#, sql

I've been looking into [How to check user id already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887160/how-to-check-user-id-already-exists) to see how to do this.

I am trying to get this working in my code, however it's not working. I don't get errors or something, but it just write data in database even if order number already exists.

The function:

```
 private void createorderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection myConnection = dbHelper.initiallizeDB();
            String query = "INSERT INTO testtabel (knaam, korder) VALUES ('" + knaamTextBox.Text + "','" + kordernrTextBox.Text + "')";
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from testtabel where korder = @korder", myConnection);
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@korder";
            param.Value = kordernrTextBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            //sqlCommand.Connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Order already exist");

            }
            else
            {
                reader.Close();
            }

            // opens execute non query 
            int rows_inserted = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (rows_inserted > 0)
            {
                label2.Text = "Order has been created";
            }

            else
            {
                Console.Write("Oops! Something wrong!");

            }



        }
```

Sorry for this kinda well known and duplicated question, but for some reason I can't get it working.

Comment: Are you connecting to the correct database??

Comment: Yes :) he is inserting as well

Comment: You don't appear to actually give your SqlCommand the SqlParameter?

Comment: shouldn't you keep this in `else`? `int rows_inserted = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: This approach will fail on concurrent inserts. You must not use it.

Comment: Did you put the parameter to the SqlCommand..?

Comment: Unique index would be very more reliable

Comment: Your reader is based on sqlCommand, which is bound to your insert statement. Your test if the data exists is bound to cmd, which you do not execute. You're running the wrong code.

Comment: Try using auto increase.

Comment: Wrong command, change `SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();` to `SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();`

Comment: Auto increment and Unique is a possibility as well, please make an answer   with the reason why I should use Unique or Auto Increment?

Comment: Put a db constraint and catch with try catch.

Comment: @VietNguyen wauw I'm ashamed now :3 Put it as answer, I will make it answered

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Getting-ID-of-the-newly-inserted-record-in-SQL-Server-Database-using-ADO.Net.aspx

Comment: @Катерина for data integrity you should use db constraints and keys. Because this logics must be in db. Coz insert can come from other sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You called the wrong command, change

```
SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

to

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

You should execute the other command first

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from testtabel where korder = @korder", myConnection);
```

The latter command, when will be executed will tell you if there is any record in the `testtabel`  table. If there is, then you should show the message:

**Order already exist**

Otherwise, you will execute your first command, that will insert the rows.

By the way, please try to avoid string concatenation, when you write sql queries. It is one of the most well known security holes. You code is open to SQL injections. You could use parameterized queries:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO testtabel (knaam, korder) VALUES (@knaam, @korder)"; 
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParamete("@knaam",knaamTextBox.Text));
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParamete("@korder",kordernrTextBox.Text));
```

Answer (score 1):

While your code is full of problems (magic pushbutton, SQL injections, absence of `using`s), there is main one. The approach you want to implement will fail on concurrent inserts, and must not be used.

Imagine, that two users run this code against the same database, using the same `korder` value:

- 1st executes `SELECT` - record with the given value doesn't exist;
- 2nd executes `SELECT` - record with the given value doesn't exist;
- 1st executes `INSERT` - record with the given value *does* exist;
- 2nd executes `INSERT` - ooops... we have a duplicate;

To avoid duplicates you must use unique indexes in database. Do not rely on your code.

Answer (score 0):

You check `HasRows` for `INSERT INTO testtabel bla...bla..bla..` not for `elect * from testtabel where korder'
Maybe you can use this (it comes from my head and not compiled, please adjust it with your own case)

```
private void createorderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection myConnection = dbHelper.initiallizeDB();
            String query = "INSERT INTO testtabel (knaam, korder) VALUES ('" + knaamTextBox.Text + "','" + kordernrTextBox.Text + "')";
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from testtabel where korder = @korder", myConnection);
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@korder";
            param.Value = kordernrTextBox.Text;
            //sqlCommand.Connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader cmdReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (cmdReader.HasRows)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Order already exist");

            }
            else
            {
                cmdReader.Close();
            }

            SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            // opens execute non query 
            int rows_inserted = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (rows_inserted > 0)
            {
                label2.Text = "Order has been created";
            }

            else
            {
                Console.Write("Oops! Something wrong!");

            }



        }
```